# functional testing using selenium - visual studio or eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I have a web app project for functional testing developed using angular and C#- cloned through git  from vsts and , I want to use selenium for testing- I started off with Test Ng framework and Selenium with sikuli integration in eclipse ide..my tests are in java.. wondering if I can continue to use eclipse or use visual studio and have tests in c#.Please advise